# Are AWS SNS Records always a single element list?

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

An AWS SNS event has a Records list which contains the message for a given notification. Is it always a single element list?

The blueprint code for reading an SNS message in node is..

```
const message = event.Records[0].Sns.Message;
```

and in python it is..

```
message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
```

Comment: From where is your message coming?

Answer (score 3):

Each aws SNS notification will contain not more than 1 message.

please read this Reliability section in SNS FAQ : https://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/

Having said that, each lambda function trigger will have just a single record

now you may have the problem why event.Records is defined as an array then? and also can it be triggered by another means with multiple entries?

answer for that would be , Records is an array because other event sources can send multiple events at one shot (like s3 events or dynamo db streams) but for SNS though it is an array will have just one sns message.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of `event` will be whatever was sent to Amazon SNS.

This might come from other AWS services ([Sample Events Published by Event Sources - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html)) or it can come from applications via the `publish()` command.

So... it contains whatever the sending application puts into that field!

Comment: The question doesn't say so, specifically, but this looks like SNS → Lambda, where the answer is always "yes," because this is the outer wrapper -- not what the application publishes to SNS.  The publisher can't influence anything outside of `event.Records[0].Sns`.